# How can I tell if my algorithm scales polynomially or exponentially? And if polynomially, at what leading order?

Tags: python, algorithm, scipy, big-o

I was wondering how exactly you can definitely show if an algorithm scales exponentially or polynomially? I have an algorithm which solves a problem with a given number of inputs, and I've been comparing how long it takes to solve with an ever-increasing number of inputs. In order to show its scaling. However, I'm not 100% sure how to highlight if the scaling is exponential or polynomial? (And, if it's polynomial at what leading order?)

What I've done is create a plot showing the scaling with an exponential function, and different order polynomial from a 2nd-order polynomial up to a 10th-order polynomial. The graph is shown below! I've also done a chi2 value (along with a p-value) for each fit, I used `scipy.stats.chisquare` to calculate the chi2 and p-value and they're shown in the legend.

I assume by having a smaller chi2 value for the polynomial fits would indicate that the the data is indeed polynomially scaling rather than expotential? If that's the case then does a smaller chi2 value corresponds to a better fit then how would you factor in overfitting? Because a 10th order polynomial fits best to the data but there's no way my algorithm scales as a 10th order polynomial?

Also, the p-value for the chi2 values is always 1? What exactly does that physically mean? Surely there should be some fluctation with the different exp./poly. fit?

Any help is apprecitated! Thank you! :)

[image]

Edit: Added a log-y version of the plot to show it's polynomial.

[image]

Comment: Looks linear here (doubling the number of inputs seems to double the runtime), but I don't think you can draw an accurate conclusion from so few inputs. Try this with various input sizes up to, say, 1000.

Comment: Plotting it on a logarithmic y-scale should give you a straight line when being exponential, while a polynomial will be curved.

Use `plt.semilogy` instead of `plt.plot`.

Comment: So, I've added a log version of the plot and it's indeed curved like you said! However, is there a way to prove what order polynomial it is?

Comment: Proof requires something other than empirical data. Analysis must be performed for proof. Generally, this may be performed using the [master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)). If your algorithm is simple enough, you don't need the master theorem.

Comment: IF it is a polynomial and you pick a large enough range, on a log-log plot it will be approximately linear and the slope will tell you the degree of the polynomial.  Of course that kind of empirical evidence is not proof.  But it can be useful.

Comment: So, I've quickly done a gradient calculation for the plot with both log on x and y, and printed the gradient. So, np.gradient(np.log(y), np.log(x)) and it's given me values in the range of .7 to 1.9. Firstly, is that correct? Secondly, if it is. How do I determine which orders? Is it an average or an extrapolation for the largest input?

Comment: Or should I fit the log-log plot with a linear fit and the gradient of that fit equals the order of the polynomial? Thank you for all the help everyone! :)